# Getting a 'got multiple values for keyword argument' error

Tags: python, django, django-views

So I'm generating a two-week expired-domains report.  It gets emailed off daily.  I've been plugging away at one particular issue I'm running into for a few days and can't for the life of me figure out why it's happening.  The error is "email_report() got multiple values for keyword argument 'duration'".  Here's the code (it's ugly, I know)..

Here's my URL:

```
url(r'^reports/domains/(?P<duration>\d+)(?P<unit>\w)/emailreport/$', email_report),
```

Here's my logic and view:

```
def expiring_domains_logic(unit):
    report_date = date.today()
    unit = unit.lower()
    if unit == 'd': report_date = report_date + timedelta(days = int(duration))
    elif unit == 'w': report_date = report_date + timedelta(weeks = int(duration))
    elif unit == 'm': report_date = report_date + timedelta(weeks = int(duration)*4)
    elif unit == 'y': report_date = report_date + timedelta(weeks = int(duration)*52)

    domains = DomainMain.objects.filter(nextrenewaldate__lte = report_date).order_by('registrarmultiid')
    cost = count_cost(domains)
    registrars = Registrars.objects.all()
    return (domains, report_date, cost, registrars)

def expiring_domains(request = None, duration = 2, unit = 'w'):
    (domains, report_date, cost, registrars) = expiring_domains_logic(unit)
    if request == None:
        return render_to_string('reports/expiring_domains.html', { 'domains': domains, 'expiration_date': report_date, 'cost': cost, 'registrars': registrars })
    else:
        return render(request, 'reports/expiring_domains.html', { 'domains': domains, 'expiration_date': report_date, 'cost': cost, 'registrars': registrars  })

def email_report(duration, unit):
    domains = expiring_domains(duration, unit) # two weeks
    email_targets = Owners.objects.filter(emailflag = 'Y')
    email_targets = (x.coemail for x in email_targets)
    email_body = domains.content # This is where we put together the email body
    msg = mail.EmailMessage('subject_here', email_body, 'no-reply@[omitted]', email_targets)
    msg.content_subtype = "html"
    msg.send()
```

Traceback:

```
File "/home/ashley/enviro/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
115. response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
Exception Type: TypeError at /reports/domains/2w/emailreport/
Exception Value: email_report() got multiple values for keyword argument 'duration'
```

Comment: Does your email_report view/function need a request as the first argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your URL defines email_report as the view, but that doesn't actually seem to be a view at all - it doesn't accept a request and return a response. The view appears to be called expiring_domains.